# Loopback include a foriegn key inside included collection

Tags: json, loopback

I have collection with nested relations i need to know how can i include those colletion using loopback filter. Here is a my loopback filter to further give an idea of the relations

```
 const filter = { 
                  "order": "createdAt DESC", 
                   "where": {"and": [{"vanId": vId}, 
                    {"isUsed": true}]}, 
                    "include": {"customData": "condition"}};
```

Now if customData has a relation with a collection named `city` then how can i include city collection inside the customData object? I just don't know how the syntax would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the loopback include docs [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Include-filter.html#include-with-filters), I was able to edit my filter like this

```
const filter = { 
                 "order": "createdAt DESC", "where": {"and": [{"vanID": vId} , 
                 {"isUsed": true}]}, "include": {"customData": ["city", "condition"]}
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation